# CheckBox touch animation on wrong position using rightDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-checkbox

I'm using custom checkbox for rtl support using rightDrawable property.

```
public class SRCheckBox extends AppCompatCheckBox {

    public SRCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        if (isRTL()) {
            this.setButtonDrawable(null);
            int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple};
            TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
            Drawable rightDrawable = ta.getDrawable(0);
            this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, rightDrawable, null);
        }
    }

}
```

but here is the problem that I'm facing with: please looke at this gif

[image: gif]

As you can see touch animation is affecting on left side (on text) instead of 
 animating **on the checkbox itself**.

I've also tried in `XML`:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/fastDecodeCB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null" // this is causing the problem
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

but it looks the same. any suggestions?

Comment: Go through this [link](https://material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html#mirroring-layout).

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the checkbox button to null effectively removing it and setting a right drawable. The right drawable responds to the clicks, but the checkbox doesn't really know that the drawable is the button (you told it there is no button), so it just does what you see.

Try the following for the init method in your custom view.

```
private void init(Context context) {
    if (isRTL()) {
        // This will flip the text and the button drawable. This could also be set in XML.
        setLayoutDirection(LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple};
        TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
        Drawable rightDrawable = ta.getDrawable(0);
        this.setButtonDrawable(rightDrawable);
        ta.recycle(); // Remember to do this.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, No, this doesn't fit my need. I'm considering this as a bug

Comment: @S.R Why do you consider this a bug? The right drawable and the button are separate things.